# Delphi Firemonkey Tab Control Android

Tags: android-studio, delphi, firemonkey

I'd want to know delphi firemonkey can do like the native tab control as others application as the example below. first did by firemonkey. second was native android i think. thanks

[Delphi Firemonkey Tab Control did by me](https://youtu.be/mCOUdmWbnww)

[Native Tab Control, I think](https://youtu.be/2Y-VmOqwbxA)

Comment: please show your code or screenshot,

Comment: You could probably emulate that using a THorzscrollbox with a FloatAnimation.Intepolation set to Elastic or Bounce and a TGestureManager. It will take a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Code will be too big to be put here but you can find it at https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe. You can also see it in action by trying this working android demo : https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/demos/ALFmxControls/Android/Release/ALFmxControls/bin/ALFmxControls.apk

Comment: i got it, but there is not a native one? i havent seen any example.

Comment: no you can't use any native with Delphi, it's not possible. Did you try the demo ?

Comment: I did try the demo and it's good but I'd want to look in others way too if there's a possible one

Comment: Native tab control is way smoother than firemonkey. Are there any way to do like that in FMX.Ani.TAnimation?

Comment: With delphi it's not possible to use native tab control ! no way at all because their is no z-order with native control and delphi draw everything on the form

Comment: maybe with stuff like https://www.turbococoa.com/ but i never tried ... but do fast you have 20% off still end of march (today)

Comment: what does turbococoa.com do ? i've never seen yet but thanks for all infos

Comment: turbococoa as i understand it's to build the visual interface with only native controls. don't know how it's work